# C++ dll Pinvoke function with function pointer struct in parameter

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I'm working on a C# code which uses a C++ dll
One function of the C++ dll takes a struct of 3 function pointers in parameter, I dont know how to manage it any tips or topics ?
I tried this but this doesnt work :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class DisplayCallBacks
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] initProgressBar ();                              
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] logMessage (int msgType, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPCWStr)] String str);
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] loadBar (int x, int n);                          
}

[DllImport("CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "setDisplayCallbacks")]
internal static extern void SetDisplayCallbacks(DisplayCallBacks c);
```

C++ prototypes :

```
typedef struct displayCallBacks
{
    void (*initProgressBar)();                             
    void (*logMessage)(int msgType,  const wchar_t* str); 
    void (*loadBar)(int x, int n);                        
} displayCallBacks;

void setDisplayCallbacks(displayCallBacks c);
```

Comment: Can't tell without seeing the c++ prototype.  You should us a structure instead of a class to make the same as c++.

Comment: I added the C++ prototypes

Comment: One issue is that none of your methods in `DisplayCallbacks` have any return types

Comment: You need to define the three types ProgressBar, logMessage, Bar and allocate the correct amount of memory for each type.  The c++ code structure is 12 bytes since each pointer is 4 bytes.  So you need 12 bytes for the structure in unmanaged memory as well as the unmanaged memory for the 3 objects.

Comment: What do you mean when you say define the three types ? declare the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IntPtr` as the type for the function pointers.
Then you can declare a delegate. Here is an example from code I wrote:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate void PrintLogDelegate(string msg);

PrintLogDelegate pld;
System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle callbackPrintLog;
IntPtr ipCBPrintLog = IntPtr.Zero;

pld = new PrintLogDelegate(PrintLogFunc);
callbackPrintLog = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(pld);
ipCBPrintLog = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(pld);


void PrintLogFunc(string msg)
{

}
```

So `ipCBPrintLog` is what you pass to C++ as a callback.

Then in your `Dispose` you have to clean up: `callbackPrintLog.Free();`